# Header Fails to Update After Specific Section Number

Tags: fancyhdr, minipage, paracol

I'm using `\pagestyle{fancy}` from the *fancyhdr* package and I want to type two parallel columns with the *paracol* package.

I'm also using the *minipage* environment to help with the justification (not sure if this is the best way, but it works ... any suggestion is also appreciated).

I want to insert the section number and title into the page header ...

The `\section` command updates the *TOC* as expected; however, the header does not.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[b6paper, 10pt, twoside, openright, final]{memoir}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
        \section{Section Title}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{minipage}
    \switchcolumn
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
        \section{Another Section Title}
        \lipsum[4]
    \end{minipage}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

The code compiles with the following Warnings:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14 ...
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11 ...
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16
```

Comment: It is hard to even guess what's happening without seeing any code. You should add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628) to show the problem.

Comment: Apart from seeing the code that causes this behavior (which is indeed necessary to diagnose the problem) it would also be useful to know if there are any errors or warnings in the log file. Even if an error or warning seems completely unrelated, it could still be responsible for wrong output later in the document.

Comment: No, `minipage` is definitely not the best way, because it disallows page breaks and with the example the boxes exceed the text height. Another problem is: *what* section title do you want to be shown?

Comment: @egreg I want the 1st section title (left column).  What do you recommend instead of minipage?